# When to use IAdaptable?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Given an object of type A, and a desire to convert it to type B if possible, when is it appropriate to use each of the following?

1. A direct cast and/or `instanceof` check

   ```
   if(a instanceof B) {
       B b = (B)a;
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Conversion through `IAdaptable.getAdapter`

   ```
   // assuming A implements/extends IAdaptable
   B b = (B)a.getAdapter(B.class);
   if(b != null) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Conversion through `IAdaptable` when `A` cannot be implicitly converted to `IAdaptable

   ```
   B b = (a instanceof IAdaptable ? (B)((IAdaptable)a).getAdapter(B.class) : a instanceof B ? (B)a : null);
   if(b != null) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Conversion through IAdapterManager

   ```
   B b = (B)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(a, B.class);
   if(b != null) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Maybe reading [that article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/what-is-iadaptable/) will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very difficult to give general rules for.

When you get something like the current selection from an Eclipse project view the object is a user interface rather than the underlying object (such as a project or file). `instanceof` will not work.

The conversion from a user interface object to the underlying object is often done using an `IAdapterFactory` which specifies a separate factory class that does the conversion. In this case you must use `Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter`.

When an object implements `IAdaptable` you have to look at the documentation or source code to see which classes it supports adapting too.

I don't think case 3 ever occurs.

I often use this code which copes with most things:

```
public final class AdapterUtil
{
  /**
   * Get adapter for an object.
   * This version checks first if the object is already the correct type.
   * Next it checks the object is adaptable (not done by the Platform adapter manager).
   * Finally the Platform adapter manager is called.
   *
   * @param adaptableObject Object to examine
   * @param adapterType Adapter type class
   * @return The adapted object or <code>null</code>
   */
  public static <AdapterType> AdapterType adapt(Object adaptableObject, Class<AdapterType> adapterType)
  {  
    // Is the object the desired type?

    if (adapterType.isInstance(adaptableObject))
      return adapterType.cast(adaptableObject);

    // Does object adapt to the type?

    if (adaptableObject instanceof IAdaptable)
     {
       AdapterType result = adapterType.cast(((IAdaptable)adaptableObject).getAdapter(adapterType));
       if (result != null)
         return result;
     }

    // Try the platform adapter manager

    return adapterType.cast(Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(adaptableObject, adapterType));
  }
}
```

Note: More recent versions of Eclipse have an `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters` class which has a similar `adapt` method.

Comment: This code does actually follow case 3 more than case 2 - `Object` isn't implicitly convertable to `IAdaptable`, so it does a runtime check with `instanceof`.